# Pass innerHTML text from JSON to a form on click event

Tags: innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am using Google books API to retrieve books information.
What I am trying to do is to pass the information that is returned (book title, author etc) and upon click fill the form.

On every API search, 10 books are returned.

**My issue is on the right side of the autoFill function, I have tried playing with it but I am missing something, I would appreciate any help with that and the logic behind that.**

Thanks!

This is how part of my form looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="bmd-label-floating" for="book_title">Book Title*</label><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="book_title" name="book_title" required="required" placeholder="Enter your book title"/>
    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Please enter a book name</span>
</div>
```

This is my autoFill function:

```
    function autoFill() {
        document.getElementById('book_title').value = json.items[i].volumeInfo.title
        document.getElementById('book_author').value = author; 
        document.getElementById('book_language').value = language; 
        document.getElementById('b_isbn').value = isbn; 
}
```

And this is how I get the books from the API:

```
$("#search_form").submit(function(e) {
    $("#books").html("");

    e.preventDefault();

    var searchQuery = $("#search_txt").val();
    searchQuery = searchQuery.split(" ").join("+");

    if (!searchQuery) {
        searchQuery = "paleo";
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + searchQuery,
        success: function(json) {
        var thumb = "";
        var htmlcontent = "";
        var author = "";
        var p_date = "";
        var language = "";
        var isbn = "";

        for (i = 0; i < json.items.length; i++) {
            if (typeof json.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks != "undefined") {
            thumb = json.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail;
            } else {
            thumb = "http://i.imgur.com/oM3MdAi.png"; // image not available
            // thumb = 'http://slems-oldboys.org.uk/library/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/library_nocover.jpg'
            }
            // Author
            if (typeof json.items[i].volumeInfo.authors != "undefined") {
            author = json.items[i].volumeInfo.authors[0];
            }
            
            // Published Date
            if (typeof json.items[i].volumeInfo.publishedDate != "undefined") {
            p_date = json.items[i].volumeInfo.publishedDate;
            }

            // Language
            if (typeof json.items[i].volumeInfo.language != "undefined") {
            language = json.items[i].volumeInfo.language;
            }

            // ISBN
            if (typeof json.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers != "undefined") {
            isbn = json.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier;
            }

            htmlcontent +=
            "<div class='thumbs' style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='autoFill(); return true;'><b>Book Title: </b>" +
            json.items[i].volumeInfo.title +
            "</b>" +
            '<img src="' +
            thumb +
            '" + alt="' +
            json.items[i].volumeInfo.title +
            '">' +
            "<br><b>Author: </b>" +
            author +
            "<br><b>Published Date: </b>" +
            p_date +
            "<br><b>Language: </b>" +
            language +
            "<br><b>ISBN_13: </b>" +
            isbn +
            '</div>' + "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
        }
        document.getElementById("books").innerHTML =
            "<div>" + htmlcontent + "</div><br>";
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

Example with an image:

This is part of the info that is being returned:

[Info being return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8k5a.png)

This is how the form looks like:

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoGxW.png)

I am trying to add some of the info that is being returned (not all) into the form, by clicking on the div that holds the info that is being returned.

Comment: Can u explain a bit more about the actual problem

Comment: Hi yes, I am trying to click on a div that contains innerHTML coming from Google Books API. the info that comes is a book title, book author and etc.

When I click on that div I want to pass the book title, book author to the form I created so that the user will not have to manually write the info himself.

Comment: lets say you have 10 books returned, you are listing all of them in front of user and asking them to click on the most relevant one and then once the user click, you fill the form with that books data...assuming this to be true....shouldn't you be callling autofill function like this `onclick='autoFill(this);` so that you can access the clicked books data in your autofill function

Comment: Hi, I have edited the post when screenshots, I don't think I can use 'this' because I don't want to pass all the info there

Comment: Actually, by passing this, u are not passing the complete info...you just pass the info of div that was clicked..by doing this ,you will just know in ur autofill form which div was clicked..you will have to access the info one by one with the help of that location u got with 'this'